# Tree structures in WebKit (Chrome)

Tags: html, google-chrome, dom, webkit, render

Web browsers make many trees when navigating web pages including DOM, CSSOM, Render, Layout trees.
(Does Layout tree exists? Or does the Layout tree just a concept which amounts to being the concept of a rendering tree with a layout property?)

I'm inspecting the Chromium source code, and I’m trying to find the data structure of each tree, and how/when/where they are made.

I found the DOM tree in WebKit, which is a tree-like structure.
Following the source code, and see some references like:

- DOM tree: https://www.slideshare.net/abapier/dom-48837015
- High-level view: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/constructing-the-object-model

What I found is the following:

- `HTMLDocumentParser` works through the function `HTMLDocumentParser::PumpTokenizer()`
- In that function, it calls `HTMLDocumentParser::ConstructTreeFromHTMLToken()` and constructs the DOM tree using `HTMLTreeBuilder`
- When finishing parsing (when the parser sees the `</html>` end tag), the function `Document::FinishedParsing()` is executed, and the `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired.

I think the CSSOM, Render, and Layout tree will be made during/after `FinishedParsing` but I can't find.

I think some important functions are the following: (I found they log important things in a trace file using the `TRACE_EVENT` function)

- `Document::FinishedParsing()`

  - `Document::UpdateStyleAndLayoutTree()`

    - `Document::UpdateActiveStyle()`: Makes `CSSStyleSheet` and `GlobalRuleset`
    - `Document::UpdateStyle()`: Setting the Style and Attach to Layout Tree

I can't find the exact data structure of the trees.
I’m looking for the following structures & functions:

- Data Structures

  - `CSSStyleSheet`
  - `StyleSheetCollection`
  - `CSSGlobalRuleSet`
  - `LayoutObject`
- Functions

  - `Element::RecalcStyle`
  - `Element::RebuildLayoutTree`

Where can I find the data on those tree structures, and what sequence should I follow?

=== Addition === 2017.08.18 16:46 KOREA

I'm analysis the code in `$CHROME/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/dom/Document.cpp$Document::FinishedParsing()` and `Document::UpdateStyleAndLayoutTree()`.

What I **thinking of** is following:

- CSSOM is made in `Document::UpdateActiveStyle()`
- Render Tree is made in `Document::UpdateStyle()`
- Layout Tree is made in `Document::NotifyLayoutTreeOfSubtreeChanges()`
  (I think Layout Tree is a concept tree, and it shared same structure with Render Tree)

Comment: If you have found the answer the please share them. I am also looking for these questions.